# Should I use the preterite or the present perfect?

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple, present-simple

I haven't seen my family for three years (now). Should I say "It's been three long years since I haven't seen my family" or "it's been three long years since I last saw my family" or "It's" in the simple present instead of "It's been"? Can you suggest me the best way to put it?

Comment: Regarding your final question, both **it's** and **it's been** are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *since* (unlike *for*) demands a point in time, the second variant is correct, because "seeing the familiy for the last time" is a point in time, which lies in the past.

You could use *I haven't seen my family* in a sentence like

> *It's been three long years **that** I haven't seen my family.*

Here *not seeing the family* and *running of time* would be two prolonged simultaneous processes.